# How to render a component passed as an attribute

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

Assume `Row` is a component like so:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
        @Column1
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        @Column2
    </div>
</div>

@code
{
    [Parameter]
    public ComponentBase Column1 { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public ComponentBase Column2 { get; set; }
}
```

Then assume that we use this like so:

```
<Row Column1="foo" Column2="foo"></Row>

@code {
    private readonly SomeComponent foo = new();
    private readonly SomeComponent bar = new();
}
```

I'd expect a row containing two columns containing the rendered components for `foo` and `bar`, but instead I get two columns containing "Example.Shared.Components.SomeComponent"

How then do you render sub-components passed into other components? Is there a better way to do this (i.e. something like `ng-content` in Angular?

As a side note, I'm looking for solutions that allow this programatically (as above), and using markup (as below):

```
<Row>
    <Column>
        <Foo></Foo>
    </Column>
    <Column>
        <Bar></Bar>
    </Column>
</Row>
```

Comment: How would you use it?  In Blazor we don't pass instances of components around, the RenderTreeBuilder instantiates them. Not saying it's totally impossible but it looks like the wrong way.

Comment: @HenkHolterman sorry that was a bit of a rubbish example. I've updated the whole question.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
        @Column1
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        @Column2
    </div>
</div>

@code
{
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment Column1 { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment Column2 { get; set; }
}
```

And then:

```
<Row>
  <Column1>
    <SomeComponent value="@somevalue"/>
  </Column1>
  <Column2>
   <SomeOtherComponent/>
  </Column2>
</Row>
```

As already stated, the Renderer instantiates all components and attaches them to the RenderTree.

Also note that all components don't necessarily inherit from `ComponentBase`, but they do all implement `IComponent`.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is [templated components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/templated-components?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

You still can't use `SomeComponent foo = new();`.

Instantiation is left to the renderer. But consider that a good thing, it lets you slip in an (item) context.

You'll also want to look at [Cascading values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/cascading-values-and-parameters?view=aspnetcore-5.0), to expose the Row to the Columns.

And finally, there are plenty of commercial and [Open](https://www.meziantou.net/creating-a-datagrid-component-in-blazor.htm) versions of a Blazor DataGrid out there. Don't reinvent the whole wheel.

Comment: Your last paragraph at best should be a comment, and not part of the answer... He did not ask for your opinion. He wants a solution to a programming question.

Comment: I sometimes agree with enet.  This is one of those times-- I wouldn't answer a programming question with advice about 3rd party controls.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 "and Open". A good example of a DataGrid is worth many SO answers.

Comment: I +1 both your post and your comment to me.  But personally, I think he WOULD be better re-inventing the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

Blazor is mostly declarative. So you should:

```
<Row>
    <Column1>
        <Foo></Foo>
    </Column1>
    <Column2>
        <Bar></Bar>
    </Column2>
</Row>
```

You don't need to do `new Foo() / new Bar()`

Of course, you can take the very circuitous route of programmatically populating the `RenderFragment`. But it is generally not worth it. Instead, use Generic components and Polymorphism.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend not thinking of filling objects with data and passing the objects around.  I'd think of Components as the expression of existing data into the html space.  Note how for each layer of data, I have nested Razor components.  So you pass DATA into the `Table` component, not `RenderFragments` or any other kind of object. The following is simplified for clarity.

```
class TableData {
    public List<RowData> Rows;
}
class RowData {
    public List<ColumnData> Columns;
}
class ColumnData {
    public string DisplayString;
}
```

**TableComponent.razor**

```
@foreach (var row in TableData.Rows){
    <DataRowComponent Data=row />
}
@code {
    [Parameter]
    public TableData TableData{get; set;}
}
```

**DataRowComponent.razor**

```
@foreach (var column in Data.Columns ){
    <DataColumnComponent Data=column />
}
@code {
    [Parameter]
    public RowData Data {get; set;}
}
```

**DataColumnComponent.razor**

```
<div>
    @Data.DisplayString
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public ColumnData Data {get; set;}
}
```